# Accordion directive, tabs not closing do click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, accordion

I am in the process of replacing all my bootstrap.js components with their respective angular counterparts using UI Boostrap. So far so good, but i can't seam to figure out to keep only the active tab open while the rest are closed. Thank you for any and all assistance.

**HTML CODE**

```
<!-- Accordion -->
<uib-accordion ng-repeat="task in activeTasks track by $index">          
  <div ng-include="'assets/views/task_list.html'"></div>         
</uib-accordionv>
```

**ng-inlcude: task_list.html**

```
<uib-accordion-group panel-class="panel panel-default">
  <uib-accordion-heading>
    <h4 class="panel-title" role="button" uib-accordion-header>{{task.title}}</h4>
  </uib-accordion-heading>  
  {{task.description}}
</uib-accordion-group>
```

**DEMO:**
[url](http://taskcomplete.carbonium.no/taskapp-ng.html)

Comment: Does it work when you put the content of task_list directly into you html code, without using ng-include?

Comment: @SpartakLalaj, tried that and no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ng-repeat` directive is generating a new `<uib-accordion>` element for each task.
You want a single `<uib-accordion>` element containing several `<uib-accordion-group>` elements (one for each task).

Comment: Thanks, that did it.

Answer (score 1):

What is `oneAtATime` ?

Don't you just want to say `close-others="true"`

Comment: Sorry that was not supposed to be there, have edited the code. Setting `close-others="true"`, did not work. Is there some JS i am missing?